# Login popup stay on incorrect login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a login popup using jquery and confirming login through php used in the page. When the user inputs the correct credentials, the page is redirected where I want, but when incorrect credentials are given the popup disappears and then again the login link is pressed to see the message on the form. I want that popup to stay with the message "Username/Password" incorrect. I have researched a lot but I haven't found an accurate answer. I have seen a few examples and they were using Ajax but please try to give me a solution without Ajax as I have never used it.

Code for login popup : index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loginpopup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#signin-box" class="loginwindow">Login/Register</a>

    <div id="signin-box" class="signin-popup">
        <a href="login.php" class="close"><img src="button_red_close.png" class="btn_close" title="Close"/></a>
        <form method="post" class="signin" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                <input class="input" id="email" name="email" type="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email address" required /></p>
                <p><input class="input" id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/></p>
                <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
                <button class="button" type="button" id="register" >Register</button></p>
                <p><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                <?php
                    require 'connect.php';
                if(isset($_POST['email'])&&isset($_POST['password'])) {
                    $email=htmlentities($_POST['email']);
                    $password=htmlentities($_POST['password']);
                    if(!empty($email)&&!empty($password)) {
                        $query="SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."' and `password`='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";
                        $query_run=mysql_query($query);
                        if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==0) {

                ?>
                <p id="message">Username/Password is incorrect.</p>
                <?php   
                        }
                        else{
                            header('Location:timer.html');
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>

            </fieldset>
          </form>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

JQuery Code : loginpopup.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/*  On clicking the Login link */

$('a.loginwindow').click(function() {
  $('.signin-popup').fadeIn(300);
});

/* On clicking close button */

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.signin-popup').remove();
});


/* On clicking register button */

$('#register').click(function(){
    $('.signin-popup').remove();
    $('.signup-popup').fadeIn(300);
});

/* Clicking close button of register popup */
$('.close_signup').click(function(){
    $('.signup-popup').remove();
});

});
```

Connection to database : connect.php

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';

$db='a_database';

$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if(!$conn)
die("Error:".mysql_error());
else
if(!mysql_select_db($db,$conn))
    die("Error:".mysql_error());
?>
```

Stylesheet : style.css

```
.signin-popup {
display: none;
background:#fff;
padding:20px 30px 20px 30px;
border: 2px solid #ddd;
float: left; 
position:fixed;
top: 20%;
left: 35%;
    z-index: 99999;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;

/* CSS3 */
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
/* Firefox */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
/* Safari, Chrome */

border-radius: 15px;
/*  earlier 3px radius */
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
/* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
/* Safari, Chrome */;
}
img.btn_close {
/* Position the close button */
float: right;
margin: -40px -40px 0 0;
}
fieldset {
    border: none;
}
form.signin{
display: block;
}
form.signin p{
color: #999;
font-size: 14px;
/*
line-height: 5px;
*/
}
form.signin .input {
border:3px solid #06F;
color: #797979;
font:normal 15px 'century gothic';
padding: 6px 4px;
width: 275px;
}

form.signin .input:focus{
border:3px solid #F30;
}
.button {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0CF,#09F);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0CF), to(#09F));
border:none;

color:#333;
cursor: pointer;
/*display: inline-block;*/
padding:8px 20px;
font:normal 15px "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
width:142px;
}
.button:hover {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#0FF,#0CF);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0FF), to(#0CF));
font-weight:bold;
}
.forgot{
text-decoration:none;
font:normal 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:#797979;
} 
#message{
text-align:center;
color:#F00;
font:bold 15px "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
```

Comment: Considering a solution without AJAX only because you've never used it is not, in my opinion, a good reason.
Besides the most proper solution imply AJAX as the page will not be recharged and so the page apparence will be constant as opposed to recharge the page and **reopen** the popup.

Comment: check the content of message in JavaScript, if exists then open the popup box.

Comment: consider cleaning up that bundle of code you just dropped. Why do we need to know about your styles?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have 2 options:

- If you don't want your page to refresh you have to use Ajax. That's quite easy with libraries like jQuery which handle all the complicated stuff.
- You don't mind that your page refreshes, therefore you can trigger your popup to appear when your page refreshes. There are several ways: a parameter in the URL, an hidden field... You can check that in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem is call a javascript function when form get submitted (onclick event of submit button. Using Ajax validate user credentials and if its correct return true or call submit method of form windows.frmname.submit().

In case of failure return false.

```
<script>

    function Validate()
    {
        Ajax call to validate..
        if sucess return true
        else return false
    }
</script>
    <input type="submit" onClick="return Validate();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy make a if condition if its wrong he will show again popup with a message
wrong password.

Don't forget to make popup display: `"flex";`